# Записать значение в переменную Angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular8

Когда я заполняю Input в компонент 'app-forms' все приходит все отлично, но я рассчитывал что так же это все будет записываться и в "obj.name" внутри компонента 'app-connect' но я ошибался, Подскажите пожалуйста как мне записывать значение input в обе переменные

Компонент который вставляю 'app-forms'

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormsModule
} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.scss']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  _name = '';

  @Input() set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
    console.log(this);
  }
  get name(): string {
    return this._name || '';
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```html
<div class="name-container">
  <div class="label">ФИО</div>
  <input class="" [(ngModel)]="name">
</div>
```

Компонент В который вставляю 'app-connect'

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-connect',
  templateUrl: './connect.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./connect.component.scss']
})
export class ConnectComponent implements OnInit {

  obj = {
    name: '',
    phone: '',
    comment: ''
  };

  obj2 = {
    name: '',
    phone: '',
    comment: ''
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  send(data, info) {
    console.log(this.entity);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <app-forms [name]="obj.name"></app-forms>
  <app-phone [phone]="obj.phone"></app-phone>
  <app-comment [phone]="obj.comment"></app-comment>
</div>
<div class="button-area">
  <button class="button" (click)="send(entity, 'first')">Отправить</button>
</div>
<div class="form2">
  <app-forms [name]="obj2.name"></app-forms>
  <app-phone [phone]="obj2.phone"></app-phone>
  <app-comment [phone]="obj2.comment"></app-comment>
</div>
<div class="button-area">
  <button class="button" (click)="send(entity, 'second')">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Без декоратора @Input такие финты невозможны.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать `@Output` для `name` в *app-forms* и `[(name)]="obj.name"` в *app-connect*.